# Pass values from input text field to a dynamic table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, dynamic

I want pass the values from the green area once I click the blue button to a dynamic table using jQuery, can you help me with which functions should I need use to do that?

[image]

Comment: There is absolutely no way this can be solved from a screenshot of the output. And even if it could, that isn't the way SO works. Show us what you've tried and what the issue is, and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just want show you the concept and check wich function could help as I'm new in Jquery, I found the awnser below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the value from the input with

```
var value = $('#id_of_input').val();
```

and then append a new `<tr>` to the table

```
$( "#id_of_table" ).append( "<tr><td>" + value + "</td></tr>" );
```

https://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Working right now, thank you so much.